# How to store nested for loop data in r before exporting with write.table

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested, write.table

I have several nested for loops in which am currently appending a write.table every iteration.  The following example is basic but should convey what I am trying to do...

```
for (i in 1:10){
  for (j in 1:10){
    for (k in 1:10){
      Data <- data.table(i+j+k)
      write.table(Data, append_TRUE, file = paste(Temp,".csv",sep"")
}}}
```

My "Data" query is much more complex than what I have show and every iteration is very slow appended to the file.  Is there a way to save the "Data" in the workspace before writing (exporting) the data out.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to store it and how would you want to retrieve it? I'm unclear what your goal is here.

Comment: As Data in the Enviroment then once the loops are completed export using write.table or write.csv.

Comment: so each iteration of the loop would grow Data by 1 or more rows? And then you just want to write it out once at the end? Are you sure the triple nested loop is really necessary?

Comment: I am conducting sqlquery commands on a very large data set.  My output adds 23 rows of data every iteration.  Current output once all loops finish consist of ~2 million rows by 21 columns of data.  Current code I have works and produces the desired output, it just takes several hours.

Comment: So each `data` is a `23x21 data.table`?

Comment: I am unsure which is more computationally/memory efficient: storing all the `data.table` to memory, then binding them or binding them after each iteration. So, this may not be the most efficient method, but it should work: `rbindlist(apply(expand.grid(1:10, 1:10, 1:10), 1, yourdataoutput))` Make sure your function can take in a vector with 3 slots as input.